# static sized valarray implementation

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

I am looking for a static-sized `std::valarray` implementation.

It should be easy to implement it by myself, but I need constexpr operations (sum,subtraction, etc.) and that is kinda boring/error prone to do, so I ask here if there is a popular implementation out there.

If I have to implement this by myself, do you think that expression-templates are worth in this case?

Comment: @Cameron : [A class template in the C++ standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray).

Comment: This would be a nice addition to Boost as well. Heavily used 3 and 4 size variants (representing 3D coordinate systems) could even be optimized with SIMD.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

What about `array` of [C++11](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/)?

But you have to implement the arithmetics yourself. Is that error-prone? I don't think so. Boring, maybe. And what about goo' ol' `valarray` from [C++99](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/valarray/)? There you have your arithmetics, already -- but, alas, they are not `constexpr`.

But you can take its implementation, wrap it around a simple `array` specialization and and you have a less error-prone, exciting task ;-)

I myself would love to try it with expression templates. But it depends how quick you have to get the code on the road. Its probably difficult to do at first, but easier to maintain (for yourself and other template magicians) in the long run. And more fun.

Comment: I'm not sure why the above was accepted as an answer as it doesn't seem to answer the question.  I was able to create a constexpr as a C-style array, but no apparent way to do it in C++.  That seems backwards.  I looked at array, it didn't solve the problem of creating a constexpr that would be evaluated at compile time, I know at least 5 ways to do it at runtime, but if it is doable in   C at compile time, then it seems C++ should have a C++ specific way to do the same.  Stroustrup goes on about using C++ style over C, but if C++ can't do it, that fall way short.